# Nodejs: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, localhost

I am currently working on an angular website running express on a nodejs server. It usually loads up perfectly when I start running it on localhost but just yesterday it suddenly started throwing this error.

```
GET / 500 3.467 ms - 1595
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "C:\node\nodetest1\routes\views"
    at EventEmitter.render (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:579:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:960:7)
    at C:\node\nodetest1\server.js:63:7
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:310:13)
    at C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
    at trim_prefix (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:310:13)
    at C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at Immediate.next (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:618:15)
    at runCallback (timers.js:674:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
```

Here is my site directory tree:

nodetest1

    bin

    routes

         libs

         partials

         views

    server.js

    package.json

I've been stuck on this for a day now and would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Edit: Heres my server code below.

```
    var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//This connects the Mongo DB
//var mongo = require('mongodb');
//var monk = require('monk');
//var db = monk('localhost:27017/appointment');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/appointment');



var app = express();

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'routes')));

//Actually uses the mongodb
//app.use(function(req,res,next){
    //req.db = db;
    //next();
//});




app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/api', require('./routes/api/appointment/'));


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Posting your server code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem:

```
res.render('error');
```

You don't have file error.ejs in views directory

Comment: So I actually didnt need that error.ejs file when starting the server previously. When I did finally put it in there it came up with the same error

Answer (score 0):

In your directory structure,

`views` is placed inside of `routes` directory.

Either you have to place it outside of `routes` directory or

define views path like this.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'routes/views'));
```